# Clearing an arraylist in many ways, but it's not freeing up memory

Tags: java, arraylist, garbage-collection, particle-system

I made a particle system thingie for fun and giggles, and it's working pretty well, even this problem is not catastrophic at all, it's just making me super curious.

I store my particles in an ArrayList. When I middle mouse click on a particle emitter, it clears the arraylist, thus deltes all particles. And it's working. However, even after the arraylist is cleared, there seems to be not a single byte freed up in my RAM.

I believe I don't have a way to reference individual particles, except through the arraylist, because I create all of them with this line:

```
particles.add(new Particle()); //particles is an ArrayList<Particle>, ofc.
```

Thus, I don't understand why the garbage collector isn't collecting them.
I tried:

using the empty() method(that's what I still use), and after/before(logically) that:

- setting all about-to-be-deleted Particle objects to null
- calling System.gc()
- overwriting the arraylist with a brand new, empty arraylist
- using trimToSize()
- starting the .jar with these parameters I found on the internets:
  -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
- waiting entire minutes, maybe the garbage collector will suddenly work.

But none of this resulted in any noticable change.

I'm checking my ram usage through good old task manager. Could the problem be simply that it's displaying incorrectly?

Comment: Use `jconsole` to attach to your app while it's running and you'll get a much better view of the memory usage.

Comment: `System.gc()` can not and will not force a garbage collection event.  You may only advise the garbage collector, but it doesn't have to listen to you.

Comment: the garbage collector will allow the ram to reach a certain amount then it will clear itself. If you want to control garbage collection do not use java and use something such as c

Comment: Unless you *really* know what you're doing, trying to measure and control the amount of storage used at such a fine level of granularity is a fool's errand.

Comment: @Todd Thanks, this actually sort of helped I guess! according to this jconsole thing, memory does get freed up. I guess JVM just doesn't let the OS use any of the RAM that it used so far which seems strange to me, making a memory leak in a java program an even more deadly error than usual.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool included in the JDK called "JVisualVM". It can be attached onto a java process and gives you quite detailed information about the garbage collection and the heap. It will also enable you to see if the objects were garbage collected or not.

Concerning the task manager: This is not a reliable source to check whether objects have been collected, as the heap stays at its size (unless it needs to increase) for quite some time.

As already mentioned in a comment above, a call to `System.gc()` may be completely ignored by your JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses a mechanism called garbage collection to return memory to the pool.  Entire books have been written about how it works, but the gist of it is that once memory is used it is not returned to the OS free memory pool until a deep garbage collelction occurs.

In the deep garbage collection, the JVM computes the storage requirement for everything that is a candidate for retention, claims a new heap from the OS, and copies the object being retained from the old heap into the new heap. Once the objects are copied, the old heap is released to the OS.

This approach means (1) you will only see memory freed by your process inside the JVM most of the time, and (2) you need to have twice as much RAM on your system as the size of the JVM, to allow for the garbage collector.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried:
>
> using the empty() method(that's what I still use) ...

Wrong already. The `empty()` method *tells you whether it is empty.* It doesn't empty it. The method you are looking for is `clear().`

> I'm checking my ram usage through good old task manager.

Wrong again. The Java garbage collector doesn't release memory back to the operating system.